# touch registered at wrong spot on ios-10 phonegap app inside iframe

Tags: ios, iframe, touch, phonegap

i have an phonegap app running on ios. (Tested on ios 10) In one of the views there is an iframe from an external source. the iframe loads fine, but the touch events inside the iframe are erratic. when i scroll down to the bottom of the iframe, there is a submit button on the form inside the iframe. when i try to tap on it, the tap is registered at near the top of the frame (the initial position of the iframe view before scrolling down the iframe). i found some articles regarding scrolling of iframe on iOS and added a div around the iframe and put the following css on it:

```
#wrap-iframe {
    position: fixed;
    top: 75px;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

but it did not solve the problem. any ideas/pointers would be highly appreciated.